# AntiVirus kills my application

Tags: android, bluetooth, antivirus

I am working on an Android application that uses **Bluetooth** to communicate with a nearby PC.
The app works greatly on my own device (**Samsung Galaxy Note 3 - CM 12.1**) but on of my beta-testers it does not.

> Simply put the app allows people to write and receive SMS from their
>   PC (with my C# WPF app) via Bluetooth & their phone.

My beta-tester is using a **Samsung Galaxy Note 4 stock ROM (Lollipop)**.

At first I thought when his screens turned off, Android would kill the MainActivity which holds on a few threads including the one maintaining the connection alive (with a `inpustream.read()` blocking method). Such behavior does not occur on my own device : I could keep the connection alive for a whole night without plugging my phone.

I was warned, though, that using **services** would avoid such problem because Android does not behave the same way from one device to another. So I updated my app and made my MainActivity use my MainService to spawn the relative threads. But it did not change a thing.

As my title suggests, the problem lies with his antivirus and more precisely : AVG.
I have no knowledge on how such antivirus work on Android and I don't even use one. **By freezing AVG with Titanium Backup** on his rooted Galaxy Note 4, my app stopepd crashing and is now working perfectly well as intended.

So I wonder, how come AVG deciced to kill my app when the device screen turned off?
How should my app behave so that this won't happen with any other users using AVG or any other antivirus ? What should I do so that my app does not look as a suspect ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the AVG did to your app.But I think that AVG may don't let your app force to turn on the bluetooth or use the Bluetooth when Android device is sleep or send/receive SMS.The AVG is one kind of antivirus apps that most of them have lots of permission request limited or power saving strategy,especially on rooted Android devices or the first part app already in the Android ROMs.

Try to make clear that what's the real point AVG did to your app.And then try to solve your problems with gentle and smart.

For example：

1.If the AVG doesn't let you use BluetoothAdapter.enable() to force to turn on the Bluetooth, try to use Activity.startActivityForResult() to let users to choose whether turn on Bleutooth or not.

2.If the AVG doesn't let you use Bluetooth when the Android device is sleep.You can try to use WakeLock.acquire() to hold the Android device.

3.If the AVG doesn't let you use SMS sending or receiving.You can changed another communication protocol, SPP or BLE or something else.

Maybe you have heard Xiaomi.If you are an Android Developer in China,because Xiaomi is very popular in China,you must deal with the adaption with Xiaomi,and then you will find that Xiaomi is really fucking for Android Developers in China.

Xiaomi doesn't some really amazing things to the original Android.For example:

1.
`AlertDialog..getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);`
you can't alert the TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT dialog on some xiaomi ROMs that they tell you nothing.

2.Xiaomi has modified lots of original themes.

3.Xiaomi has changed the Android alarm timing mechanism while the device is sleep which is called Wake-Up-Alignment.This is really terrible for the apps that with the function of timing.

The above problems are that I met in Android development, some problems I can resolve it, some you don't have any chances to change it.

Remember that:The adaption with Android devices is that you must make your users know you app works on most of the popular Android Devices,the developers try to make the app run on most Android devices,but it maybe not work on some Android devivces with customized ROMs or with some special third part apps.That's it ,that's true, that's Android.

If the problem can't be solved,it's not a problem!

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am afraid I have not explained myself more clearly. All of the above works. I can use Bluetooth, I can send SMS without a single issue. The issue is that AVG kills my app. It kills it as soon as it goes to background when the screen locks. That's it. AVG won't leave my app and the on-going Bluetooth connection alive: it will stop it. Regarding the part where there are Android is of many clothes, that is acceptable. But AVG killing my app, that I cannot accept.